# Recursion in regular expression is not working

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to separate type and arguments in this expression:

```
tf->get_TextState()->set_TextMatrix(std::shared_ptr<DOM::Matrix>(new DOM::Matrix(m->get_M11(), -m->get_M12())));
```

I create the following regex:

```
std::shared_ptr[ \t]*<(?'type'[A-Z,:,_,a-z,<,>]*){1}>[ \t]*\([ \t]*new[ \t]*(\k'type'){1}(?'args'.*)
```

The result is:

Group "type": `DOM::Matrix`

Group "args": `(m->get_M11(), -m->get_M12())));`

The problem in a "args" group because I need only the: `(m->get_M11(), -m->get_M12())`

For do that, I change `.*`  to: `\([^()]*+(?:(?R)[^()]*+)*+\)`

This expression separetly very well work on: `(m->get_M11(), -m->get_M12())));`
With expected result: `(m->get_M11(), -m->get_M12())`

But when I add it in whole pattern i.e.:

```
std::shared_ptr[ \t]*<(?'type'[A-Z,:,_,a-z,<,>]*){1}>[ \t]*\([ \t]*new[ \t]*(\k'type'){1}(?'args'\([^()]*+(?:(?R)[^()]*+)*+\))
```

It do not matching anything.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What language is this? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: What is the output you're looking for (and what is the `*+` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a subroutine call to recurse the `args` subpattern with `(?&args)`, but not the *whole* pattern (`(?R)` recurses the whole pattern!).

Use

```
std::shared_ptr\h*<(?'type'[A-Z:_a-z<>]*)>\h*\(\h*new\h*\k'type'(?'args'\([^()]*+(?:(?&args)[^()]*+)*+\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ3uV8/1)

Note that I replaced `[ \t]` with `\h` (it matches horizontal whitespace) to shorten the pattern, removed redundant `{1}` quantifiers and groups.

BTW, here is an alternative expression that does the same thing:

```
std::shared_ptr\h*<(?'type'[A-Z:_a-z<>]*)>\h*\(\h*new\h*\k'type'(?'args'\((?>[^()]|(?&args))*\))
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ3uV8/2)

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! Unfortunately I cant' set the +1 but in my case I estimate this answer +10